# Integrating twitter sdk with android app in android studio?

Tags: twitter, android-studio, social-networking

I want to share posts on twitter from my android application, For this i need to integrate the twitter sdk with my android application in android studio. The examples that i am getting is for integrating twitter in eclipse.

Can any bodyhelp as how to integrate twitter sdk in android studio?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the "*or provide any links*" at the end because asking for an "*off-site resource*" is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

There's a plugin for android studio to integrate twitter that is Fabric.

**Step 1-** Go to [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com)

**Step 2-** Download [FabricAndroidStudioPlugin](https://fabric.io/onboard).

**Step 3-** After downloading, follow [this](https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio) link to add this plugin in android studio.

**To add this plugin in android studio**

Go to `File` ->> `Settings` ->> Click on `Plugins` -->> then click on `Install plugin from disk` button -->> then select that FabricAndroidStudioPlugin zip file and ok..!! An icon of fabric will be there on toolbar. Then click that icon and follow the steps. fabric will now do everything automatically.

Comment: What about GUI for Application ?

Comment: http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/06/android-twitter-fabric-sdk-integration.html#.VhyUYDWY7aU

Answer (score 0):

It helps me for Twitter integration in android application.

This is offical Twitter Kit for Android(Twitter SDK)

check this link
https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation

```
dependencies {
// Include all the Twitter APIs
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
// (Optional) Monetize using mopub
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
}

repositories {
 jcenter()
}

public class CustomApplication {
public void onCreate() {
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
.logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
.twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
.debug(true)
.build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
}
}
```