# Error with firebaseUI when building the project

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I try to use firebaseUI, but there is An error occurred like this .how can I solve it:

[image]

My build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: Don't post a picture of an error message please. Instead post the actual text of the error message, so that it becomes searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error, Firebase UI demo need *Twitter* API, so add *Twitter* API in your gradle. 
For more check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529932/integrating-twitter-sdk-with-android-app-in-android-studio).

Comment: Thank you .it is resovled.:)